# How can I fix this bubble sort function in C?

Tags: c, sorting

I am passing an array of flight information and flight count to a sorting function. Within the flight array are flight id's, for example (H100.15005), and my goal is to sort the flight information ascending order based on the flight ids. How can I fix the bubble sort function?

Language: C Platform: Virtual machine on Mac OS X OS: Ubuntu (64-bit)
16.04 LTS Editor: Vim 7.4 Constraints: Must use basic sorting algorithm.

Here is the before and after sorting outputs along with the code:

```
    Initial Flights
        Flight Id    From Dest Depart Avail   Unit Price
        H100.15005   SAT  HOU  08:00      4        65.00
        H111.15009   SAT  HOU  17:00     10        65.00
        H555.15022   SAT  DFW  08:00     70        70.00
        H444.15015   ATL  NYC  08:00     10       130.00
        H200.15010   ATL  HOU  08:00     20       120.00
        H222.15005   HOU  ATL  10:00     15       125.00
        H333.15010   ATL  NYC  13:00     20       130.00
        H444.15001   ATL  NYC  08:00     10       130.00
        H100.15006   SAT  HOU  08:00     12        65.00
        H333.15012   ATL  NYC  12:55     60       130.00
        H666.15020   NYC  ATL  01:45     50       140.00
    Sorted Flights
        Flight Id    From Dest Depart Avail   Unit Price
        H100.15005   SAT  HOU  08:00      4        65.00
        H111.15009   SAT  HOU  17:00     10        65.00
        H555.15022   SAT  DFW  08:00     70        70.00
        H444.15015   ATL  NYC  08:00     10       130.00
        H200.15010   ATL  HOU  08:00     20       120.00
        H222.15005   HOU  ATL  10:00     15       125.00
        H333.15010   ATL  NYC  13:00     20       130.00
        H444.15001   ATL  NYC  08:00     10       130.00
        H100.15006   SAT  HOU  08:00     12        65.00
        H333.15012   ATL  NYC  12:55     60       130.00
        H666.15020   NYC  ATL  01:45     50       140.00



     void sortFlights(Flight flightM[], int iFlightCnt) {
            int i;
            int j;
            Flight flightIdTemp;


            for(i = 0; i < (iFlightCnt - 1); i++) {
                for(j = (iFlightCnt - 1); j > i; j--) {
                    if(flightM[j-1].szFlightId > flightM[j].szFlightId) {
                        flightIdTemp = flightM[j-1];
                        flightM[j-1] = flightM[j];
                        flightM[j] = flightIdTemp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you edit your post to include a description of what is currently wrong with the implementation?

Comment: use `strcmp` instead of `>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `szFlightId` is probably a character string and you want to compare the content of the two strings. This does not work with the `>` operator in C which will only compare the memory addresses. You need to use the function `strcmp()` instead.

```
if (strcmp(flightM[j-1].szFlightId, flightM[j].szFlightId) > 0)
```

(Actually we do not know the type, but the prefix `sz` has often been used to mark zero terminated strings. Some Hungarian developer at Microsoft introduced this convention which is therefore called Hungarian Notation.)

Answer (score 0):

```
     void sortFlights(Flight flightM[], int iFlightCnt) {
        int i;
        int j;
        Flight flightIdTemp;


        for(i = 0; i < (iFlightCnt - 1); i++) {
            for(j = (iFlightCnt - 1); j > i; j--) {
                if(strcmp(flightM[j-1].szFlightId, flightM[j].szFlightId) > 0) {
                    flightIdTemp = flightM[j-1];
                    flightM[j-1] = flightM[j];
                    flightM[j] = flightIdTemp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: A bit of explanation might help. And why copy the complete code when only one line is modified?